# Masking GeoTIFF file after GeoJSON through rasterio - "Input shapes do not overlap raster"

Tags: geojson, geotiff-tiff, masking, rasterio, planet

So my intention is quite simple:
I have a 4-Band TIFF file I want to crop after a `polygon` shape. However, I'm getting the following two exceptions

- `WindowError: windows do not intersect`
- `ValueError: Input shapes do not overlap raster.`

after running this code

```
with rasterio.open(raw_filename) as dataset:
   out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(dataset, [polygon], crop=True)
```

Now this seems really strange to me because the same `polygon` was used to query my data. Moreover, I made sure there's a 100% overlap between them 
prior to downloading and I can see it that the areas overlap.

My `polygon` is the blue box below:

[image: AOI]

with the values:

```
print(polygon)
# {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[36.044253, 5.166209], [36.044253, 5.180148], [36.061434, 5.180148], [36.061434, 5.166209], [36.044253, 5.166209]]]}
```

And my file looks something like this:

```
image = rasterio.open(raw_filename)
rasterio.plot.show((image, 1))
```

[image: Full shape]

which might not mean much to you, but I can guarantee that's in there.

Digging a little bit on my own I came to the conclusion that there ought to be something in the configuration of the GeoTIFF file that's not compatible with / adjusted to my `polygon` coordinates, most probably through the `dataset.trasnform` affine transformation matrix as seen [here](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/rasterio/features.py#L404).

My file's aforementioned matrix, bounding box and coordinate reference system are as follows:

```
print(dataset.bounds)
# BoundingBox(left=160803.0, bottom=567978.0, right=187356.0, top=581073.0)

print(dataset.transform)
# | 3.00, 0.00, 160803.00|
# | 0.00,-3.00, 581073.00|
# | 0.00, 0.00, 1.00|

print(dataset.crs)
# +init=epsg:32637
```

Does anyone have any insight into why this might happen?

Comment: Just because you can plot two datasets as overlapping doesn't mean they share a coordinate reference -- It just means that they have correct metadata. Cropping an image requires a bounding box in the same CRS. GeoJSON is always geographic, so it is the wrong choice to clip a projected image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to crop the GeoTiff file as intended.

The issue was that my GeoJSON / shape / polygon had its points in "normal" coordinate reference systems (which actually is `epsg:4326` or WSG 84) while my geoTiff data is expressed in `epsg:32637`.

I used the following function to project my `polygon`:

```
def project_wsg_shape_to_csr(shape, csr):
  project = lambda x, y: pyproj.transform(
    pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326'),
    pyproj.Proj(init=csr),
    x,
    y
  )
  return shapely.ops.transform(project, shape)


projected_shape = project_wsg_shape_to_csr(shapely.geo.shape(polygon), 'epsg:32637')
```

Comment: GeoJSON projection is not EPSG:4326

Comment: I beg to differ: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#section-4 says that GeoJSON standard is WSG 84

Comment: Yes GeoJSON is `urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC::CRS84` which has geographic coordinates expressed in expressed in **lon/lat** order. EPSG:4326 has geographic coordinates expressed in expressed in **lat/lon** order. https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326.  Please note that the EPSG registry is the definitive source for the definition of EPSG codes

Comment: Don't worry though W3C also got it wrong ~ https://github.com/w3c/sdw/pull/791

Comment: @BuruianăCătălin I had the same problem but couldn't get your solution to work: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307532/rasterio-error-input-shapes-do-not-overlap-raster-but-reprojection-not-working (grateful if you have any other suggestions)