# Rasterio error: Input shapes do not overlap raster but reprojection not working

Tags: python, gdal, masking, rasterio

I'm trying to use `rasterio` (v1.0.13) and `fiona` to perform a raster clip on a geotiff using a geojson polygon. For reference, the clip works perfectly from the command line using GDAL:

```
gdalwarp -cutline tmp_yard.geojson  -crop_to_cutline -of GTiff -r cubic leaf_index.tif tmp.tif
```

[image]

[image]

But the following does not (as per rasterio docs: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/masking-by-shapefile.html#)

```
with fiona.open("tmp_yard.geojson", "r") as geojson:
    features = [feature["geometry"] for feature in geojson]
    pprint.pprint(features)
    with rasterio.open("leaf_index.tif") as src:
        out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, features,
                                                           crop=True)
        out_meta = src.meta.copy()
```

Produces error:

> [{'coordinates': [[(-11680153.379982425, 4825380.211452511),
>                      (-11680101.881582342, 4825359.649286965),
>                      (-11680099.47141429, 4825337.825410188),
>                      (-11680153.677325355, 4825348.074481825),
>                      (-11680153.379982425, 4825380.211452511)]],   'type': 'Polygon'}]
>
> ValueError: Input shapes do not overlap raster.

I tried to apply the solution here: [Masking GeoTIFF file after GeoJSON through rasterio - "Input shapes do not overlap raster"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303089/masking-geotiff-file-after-geojson-through-rasterio-input-shapes-do-not-overl) to reproject my geoson, using:

```
import shapely
import pyproj
def project_wsg_shape_to_csr(shape, csr):
    project = lambda x, y: pyproj.transform(
        pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326'),
        pyproj.Proj(init=csr),
        x,
        y
      )
    return shapely.ops.transform(project, shape)

yard=project_wsg_shape_to_csr(features, 'epsg:4326')
```

However, this produces the error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'is_empty'

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Without the full traceback for your error, it's tough to say for sure where the error is happening, BUT, it sounds like your `shape` might be a list instead of a Shapely geometry.  Could you check that your geometry is correct?

Comment: Yes, I had that wrong but I couldn't figure out how to fix it. I solved the problem by giving up on reprojecting on the geoJSON side and instead reprojecting the geoTIFF to WSG84 instead before applying the clip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code tries to convert from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:4326.
But your data is actually in EPSG:3857 (wild guess on my end).
You need to use EPSG:3857 as "source" CRS.

Try this (untested):

```
project = lambda x, y: pyproj.transform(
    pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:3857'),
    pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326'),
    x,
    y
)
yard = shapely.ops.transform(project, features)
```

GeoJSON had no specification until https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946 so older GeoJSON might not be in WGS84 which rasterio might assume to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, reprojecting the geoTIFF using QGIS (instead of trying to unsuccessfully reproject geoJSON) to WSG84 did the trick and made the `rasterio` example work.